# Vue Js displaying object in qoutes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, documentation

i faced an issue. I have an array of "Lessons" in which i have stored 5 objects. Each of them have parameter (url). Example:

```
Lessons: [
        {
          url: "../assets/Math.png",
          Title: "Lesson",
          Subject: "Math",
          Location: "London",
          Price: "£100",
          Spaces: 5,
        },
```

Now i did v-for to display each of them, everything is working except i dont know how to show the image i have in the /assets folder. i have tried simple way `img src=" {{ lesson.url }}"` and this one:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3" v-for="lesson in Lessons" :key="lesson.id">
  <div class="card" >
   <img src="'${lesson.url}'" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
```

can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: I made a quick update to my answer as I forgot to add the template code. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use image routes in this way you must first import them for Webpack to be able to process them from the data:

```js
import mathImg from  "../assets/Math.png"

// in your data
Lessons: [
        {
          url: mathImg, // use the import name
          Title: "Lesson",
          Subject: "Math",
          Location: "London",
          Price: "£100",
          Spaces: 5,
        }
]
```

in your template

```
<img :src="Lessons.url" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to bind the src attribute like so:

```
<img :src="lesson.url" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot the `:`

```
  <img :src="`${lesson.url}`" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
```

and you also can

```
 <img :src="lesson.url" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
```